# is it possible to set different price levels per currency?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, currency

Magento 1.9.0.1

Store based in europe with euro prices

i know it is possible to use the currency converter and that works nicely

But...

For the US we need a different price level. Is it possible to have a certain pricelevel for euro and another price level for usd for a product in the same store?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have a different attribute known as 'usPrice' or something similar.  When you detect the user is using that currency simply display instead of the 'regular' price.  Do a similar thing in the cart, etc.

Magento uses 'get' functions to get attributes from objects.  In this scenario the object will be something called a Product.  These get functions look something like this:

```
$productPrice = $product -> getPrice();
```

Now, in the admin side of Magento you can define something called a 'custom attribute'.  In your example we can call this custome attribute usPrice, which we will access using this:

```
$usProductPrice = $product -> getUsPrice();
```

On the products page you can use an if statement to get either the productPrice or the usProductPrice, which ***should*** look something like:

```
if(*however you're detecting source of user* == 'United States'){
    $price = $product -> getUsPrice();
}
else{
    $price = $product -> getPrice();
}
```

Or, if you have your own conversion rate you could just multiply that by the base price and be done with it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it is possible... but this doesn't make sense to me though... would you mind explaining a bit more so a non programmer can follow this ;-)

Comment: @carlo I added some more to the answer.

Comment: This clarifies it some more thanks :-) ... in think i would need to find out how to detect the user source (ip?)

Comment: Personally I'd use something like a dropdown menu to select difference currencies / languages / etc.  But that's just me. Select 'answered' if you feel I have answered this question and open another one as to how to detect the country that the user resides within!